# Gravitational potential at large distance tensor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Prove that for a bounded body with mass disturbution $\rho (\vec{r'})$

The gravitational potential of the body can be expressed as

$\phi(\vec{r'})=-\gamma\frac{M}{r}+\frac{3\gamma}{2r^5}r_ir_j(I_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}I_{kk}\delta_{ij})$

where $I_{ij}=\int_V dV' \rho(\vec{r'})(r'^2-r_ir_j\delta_{ij})$

Also $\phi(\vec{r})=-\gamma \int_V dV' \frac{\rho\vec(r')}{|\vec(r')-\vec(r)|}$

Not sure how to obtain the higher order term, and also should $I_{kk}$ be zero

Comment: *Should $I_{kk}$ be zero?* Do you think that $I_{kk}$ should be zero because you think that $\delta_{kk}$ is 1? It’s 1+1+1=3. The notation is using the Einstein summation convention where a repeated index like $k$ is summed over 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: Sorry I have wrote it the other way around now I have corrected it

Comment: After your revision the integral for $I_{ij}$ doesn’t make sense because it is now a scalar rather than a tensor. Each term must have free $i$ and $j$ indices.

Comment: There should also be primes on $r_i$ and $r_j$.

Comment: After revising you are right, it should be as it was earlier

Comment: In that case, you should edit it again.